# is there any log for data bricks cluster who installed jar files or packages

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I got error due to env jar file installed by anonymous user so here I want to track who installed that jar file is there any way to verify who installed what on data bricks cluster is there any log to find out this user

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to retrieve information on who installed library on cluster. I installed `mlflow` library on cluster and check Log4j output. But there is no information available.

Below is the screenshot of Log4j output.

```
22/08/03 15:27:12 INFO SharedDriverContext: Successfully attached library python-pypi;mlflow;;NONE; to Spark
22/08/03 15:27:12 INFO LibraryState: [Thread 131] Successfully attached library python-pypi;mlflow;;NONE;
22/08/03 15:27:12 INFO DriverCorral: [Thread 128] AttachLibraries - candidate libraries: List(PythonPyPiPkgId(mlflow,None,None,List()))
22/08/03 15:27:12 INFO DriverCorral: [Thread 128] AttachLibraries - new libraries to install (including resolved dependencies): List()
```

[image]